# php rename before sending to sever

Tags: php, rename

I'm trying to rename a file before it is uploaded and i dont seem to be doing it correctly...

```
$write_image($new_img, $new_file_path . '/', $options['upload_dir'] . 'HOME.jpg' . '/'), 100);
```

The new_file_path looks like so:

```
/home/content/h/e/f/xxx/html/admin/uploading/example/thumbnails/column.jpg/
```

And the $options['upload_dir'] . 'HOME.jpg' . '/' looks like so:

```
/home/content/h/e/f/xxx/html/admin/uploading/example/thumbnails/HOME.jpg/
```

It doesn't seem to work because it doesn't name the file and it gives me an error (like it was looking for the ordinal name and all)...

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Comment: try to remove the slash after the image name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected it by just doing

```
$write_image($new_img, $options['upload_dir'] . 'bob.jpg', 100);
```

David

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing slash. They should be only present for directories and not files. And is the function call really supposed to start with a `$`?

And you have a syntax error. You have one extra closing parenthesis.

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis